# RC5 encryption and decryption of data using JCE

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I need an java RC5 encryption and decryption algorithm.

Comment: I use my own impl. of RC5 but there are tons of impl. on the net. Just pick one.

Answer (score 3):

The JCE includes support for RC5 but Sun has *not* implemented RC5 in any of their providers. The Bouncycastle provider, on the other hand, does include RC5. So if you just add the bouncycastle provider you should be able to use RC5 through the JCE (e.g. `Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RC5/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`)

However, just because you can get it for free does not mean you can legally use it for free. For example, in the U.S. you would need to obtain a license from the RC5 patent holder.

EDIT: The RC5 patent has expired in the United States.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK comes with a JCE provider supporting RC5. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html and look for the explanations on the Cipher class to get you started.

Also look at the [RC5ParameterSpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/RC5ParameterSpec.html) class.

Comment: I don't think any of the Sun JCE providers includes the actual RC5 algorithm. It is includes *support* for RC5, so that *if* some provider implemented it then you could use it. In fact, the Sun providers do not include any patented algorithms. RC5 is patented.